# Multi Threading in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

In C#,I want to do multi threading say I have Thread T1 and Thread T2. I do the below:

```
Thread T1 = new Thead(some_func).Start() 
Thread T2 = new Thread(some_other_func).Start().
```

By doing this am I spawning threads across the cores or in the single core. If it is in single core, how can I do it across cores. Is there any built in method? or i have to do it explicitly?. some people suggest to use ThreadPool. What actually happens when we use thread pool and how is it actually used?

Comment: When you create a thread the OS is responsible for resources allocation. It can get a separate core if it's available or run on the same core. using the ThreadPool is **usually** the right thing to do.

Comment: Please tell me how to use the thread pool.

Comment: Please google how to use the thread pool. (Hint: class is named `ThreadPool`)

Comment: Using [`Parallel.Invoke(some_func, some_other_func)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992634(v=vs.110).aspx) is a cleaner way of invoking functions in parallel. Although it probably offers no more guarantees of parallelism than the method above, it does mean you should almost never have to worry about creating threads yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some quick answers:

> 1. By doing this am I spawning threads across the cores or in the single core?

You are creating multiple threads. Whether they execute on different cores is entirely up to the framework and (because .NET typically delegates the job to the OS) the operating system. However, if cores are available then typically they will be used.

> 2. If it is in single core, how can I do it across cores.
> 3. Is there any built in method? or i have to do it explicitly?.

See above. You have no real control over this. Windows and .NET provide mechanisms to *restrict* which cores a thread runs on (i.e. to set "thread affinity" to a specific core or group of cores), but you can't force your collection of threads to use more cores than .NET would otherwise provide.

Fortunately, as I mention above, .NET will generally use as many cores as are available.

> 4. some people suggest to use ThreadPool. What actually happens when we use thread pool and how is it actually used?

A thread pool is a construct that abstracts a collection of threads, each of which can be reused as needed. This is useful because there is some overhead (especially on Windows…not so much on *nix operating systems) when creating threads.

The .NET thread pool starts out empty (or with a very small number of threads). When you queue something to it, it first looks for an available idle thread. If there is one, it signals that thread to execute the delegate you queued to the thread pool. Otherwise, it creates a new thread (possibly waiting a brief moment first in case some thread pool thread becomes idle and can be reused), and uses that thread to execute your delegate.

The .NET `ThreadPool` class encapsulates this behavior. Note that the thread pool is used by a number of mechanisms, including direct asynchronous invocation of delegates (i.e. the `BeginInvoke()` method each delegate type has), various asynchronous APIs in the framework, and certain kinds of asynchronous operations started using the `Task` class.

It is *not* used when you create a `Thread` object explicitly.

For a more detailed understanding of threading and the .NET thread pool, see the various MSDN documentation pages on the subject. IMHO any more detail than the above would be too broad for a StackOverflow question.